# Anaconda-Navigator - Ubuntu16.04

Tags: anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

This is ubuntu16.04. I can open Anaconda-Navigator from the terminal using 
`anaconda-navigator`, but when I click on it, it doesn't open. What am I missing?

Comment: In addition to the answers given here, I'd like to add that after installing Anaconda in one terminal, you must open a new terminal in order to open the navigator.

Answer (score 164):

To run anaconda-navigator:

```
$ source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root
$ anaconda-navigator
```

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04, and its working for me.Thank you so much.

Comment: How do we make this permanent so we don't have to do this every time the computer is restarted?

Comment: Thiis also works for me! Notice that often you can replace the first command to `conda activate`

Answer (score 54):

Use the following command on your terminal (`Ctrl + Alt + T`):-

```
$ conda activate
$ anaconda-navigator
```

Comment: I was in another conda environment. `conda activate` changed env to base and it worked for me!

Answer (score 46):

it works :

```
export PATH=/home/yourUserName/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

after that run `anaconda-navigator` command. remember anaconda can't in Sudo mode, so don't use sudo at all.

[image: Anaconda Running screenshot]

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 19.04 and it works for me. Thank you

Comment: @MohammadHeydari, even after executing export command I am getting command not found error. Please help to resolve the issue

Comment: @megha, Did you test the command in Sudo mode? cause it doesn't work in sudo mode

Comment: Hi, is there any downside to adding this in my `.bashrc` so that I don't need to add the path every time? I just hope it won't break the system!

Answer (score 24):

Simply create a new text document called "anaconda-navigator.desktop" in your home directory by the terminal command:

```
gedit anaconda-navigator.desktop
```

Then enter the following in your text document:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Anaconda
Version=2.0
Type=Application
Exec=/path/to/anaconda-navigator
Icon=/path/to/selected/icon
Comment=Open Anaconda Navigator
Terminal=false
```

Save the file, then move it to your local applications folder:

```
mv anaconda-navigator.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Once this is done, you will be able to search for "Anaconda" on your applications screen, right click, and add to favorites. This way you don't have to go through the terminal every time!

[image: Finished Product]

Comment: By far the most helpful answer. It would gain from noting that the default path is `/home/USERNAME/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator` and the icon is in `/home/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/pythonVERSION/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/static/images/anaconda-icon-256x256.png` .

Comment: atlas Thank you. This helps a lot. Also, @FvD Thank you for sharing the path details.

Answer (score 23):

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. When I installed anaconda I was facing the same problem. I tried this and it resolved my problem.

step 1 : $ conda install -c anaconda anaconda-navigator​

step 2 : $ anaconda-navigator

Hope it will help.

Comment: Work for me with ubuntu 16.04 64 bits. I have some problems with permission in anaconda directory but i use - sudo chwon myuser:mygroup -R anaconda-folder - and after that i try step 1 again and work fine. Thank you from Brasil.

Answer (score 12):

add anaconda installation path to .bashrc

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/username/anaconda3/bin"
```

load in terminal

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

run from terminal

```
$ anaconda-navigator
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

First go to the anaconda3 binaries directory by running

```
 cd anaconda3/bin
```

and now use this following command to open the anaconda-navigator

```
./anaconda-navigator
```

Answer (score 3):

If all the above methods are not working, you probably install anaconda with root privileges. Remove it with `sudo rm -rf /root/anaconda3` and reinstall without `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

OPEN TERMINAL

```
export PATH=/home/yourUserName/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
anaconda-navigator
```

This will get you going! cheers!

Answer (score 0):

By default anaconda is installed at **/root/anaconda3** path, if you want to access it then you should run

- su -
- cd /root/anaconda3/bin
- ./jupyter-notebook or ./anaconda-navigator

If you want to change the path, just login as a admin and copy folder to **/opt/** or reinstall it.

Answer (score -1):

I am running Anaconda Navigator on Kubuntu 17.04 & getting a successful launch of the navigator window.  Not knowing any of your error messages or statement; you could try reinstalling with command:
conda install -c anaconda anaconda-navigator

Answer (score -2):

In my case, I don't need to set up anything further after installing Anaconda on Ubuntu

here is my screenshot for the version info. 
[image]

Comment: It might not be, but basically there is no further action needed to run Anaconda navigator in my case like fab_rat below. So i shared my case here.