# If I don’t activate the base environment, I can’t launch anaconda-navigator, how do I fix it?

Tags: anaconda, conda, ubuntu-20.04

I've installed anaconda3 on ubuntu 20.04. After the installation, if I don't insert this command `conda config --set auto_activate_base False`, I cannot launch anaconda-navigator. Additionaly I can’t start the application except from terminal. I uninstalled and installed the application several times and restarted the pc, thinking that the problem would be fixed. Then when anaconda starts the screen turns out to have problems I don’t know if it’s a bug or something else.
Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

[image: Auto base enviroment False]

[image: Auto base enviroment True]

[image: Anaconda start]

Comment: This issue is already solved. check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43030871/anaconda-navigator-ubuntu16-04

Comment: Even though you don't auto-activate **base**, you can still activate it when you need it with `conda activate`, and deactivate it once you've launched navigator with `conda deactivate`.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)

```
$ source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root
$ anaconda-navigator
```